# NYC's death certificate: "as no inquiry as to the facts has been provided by law."

Tags: translation

On NYC's death certificate, there is this sentence:

> The department of Health and Mental Hygiene does not certify to the
>   truth of the statements made thereon, as no inquiry as to the facts
>   has been provided by law.

I am trying to translate it into Chinese: 鉴于没有法务部门作出特殊要求，卫生局不对以上陈述的真实性负责。

It is a little inaccurate, but I can't think of any better translation that would make sense in Chinese. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think the meaning of "as no inquiry as to the facts has been provided by law" is distorted by the translation ... it should be interpreted as "... because under the provisions of the law, no ***official investigation*** (=inquiry) for the facts has been our obligation." So, it would better be translated as 鉴于法律没有要求对事实进行调查，健康与心理卫生局不对以上陈述的真实性负责。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**健康与心理卫生局依法未对事实进行调查，故不对上述声明的真实性负责。**

 - **健康与心理卫生局**: The department of Health and Mental Hygiene
 - **依法未对事实进行调查**: as no inquiry as to the facts has been provided by law
 - **不对上述声明的真实性负责**: does not certify to the truth of the statements made thereon
The rest is styling choice.

Comment: First of all, "健康与心理卫生局" is the translation appeared in the official Chinese edition documents.

Comment: @Stan I think you are right. 健康与心理卫生局 does sound better to me. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: 健康与心理卫生局... so weird in Chinese lol

Comment: incorrect answer. the translation of `未对事实进行调查: no inquiry as to the facts has been provided` is incorrect.

Comment: @wilson You are right. I shouldn't split the phrase "as provided by law". I will edit my answer. Let me know what you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

因沒有法定聆訊, 健康與心理衛生局不會證實以上陳述的真確性.

- certify = 證實
- truth = 真確性
- statements = 聲明 / 陳述
- made thereon = 有關 / 以上
- inquiry as to the facts = 聆訊 / 研訊
- .... provided by law = 法律規定

Actually, the phrase "no inquiry as to the facts has been provided by law" somehow appears to me that the Dept. does not have the authority to do so.

Comment: *"inquiry as to the facts = 聆訊 / 研訊"*: "聆訊" would be a better choice here. "研訊" is almost exclusively used in "死因研訊" ([Inquest](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquest)), which is a specific type of "聆訊" (Inquiry).